# Error with SSL and NSURLSessionDownloadTask

Tags: ios, ssl, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I've had a NSURLSessionDownloadTask that worked perfectly fine for awhile, but today it stopped working and called the `func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential!) -> Void)` method. It seems as thought if I attempt to download the image using SSL, it will attempt a challenge, and if SSL is not used, it works just fine. I'm not sure how to handle this, as I'm not sure what credentials I would provide to the challenge - quite new to networking on iOS. How should I proceed?

```
func downloadProfilePicture(path: String) {
        println("1")
        let filePath: NSString = NSString(string: "https://www.domain.com/uploads/\(path).png")

        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: .defaultSessionConfiguration(), delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
        let downloadTask = session.downloadTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: filePath)!)

        downloadTask.resume()
        println("2")
    }

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential!) -> Void) {
        println("6")
        println(challenge.protectionSpace.description)
    }

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {

    println("3")
    var image: UIImage = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: location)!)!

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.imageView.image = image
        println("4")
    })
}
```

Console:

```
1
2
6
<NSURLProtectionSpace: 0x7fcc5a4b4ae0>: Host:www.domain.com, Server:https, Auth-Scheme:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust, Realm:(null), Port:443, Proxy:NO, Proxy-Type:(null)
```

Note: I haven't changed the settings on my web server for some time, and the SSL certs are still valid.